Annihilator of operator spaces
I was studying the annihilator of vector spaces. More precisely, I am interested to study it in the perspective of Banach spaces and operator spaces.

Definition. If $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$ and $S$ is a subset of $V$, the annihilator of $S$ is the set $S^0$ of linear functionals $f$ on $V$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$ for every $\alpha$ in $S$.

Can anyone please allow me to know a few examples of the operator spaces and their annihilator subspaces? For example, what is the annihilator subspace of the space of all compact operators? What is the annihilator subspace of the space of all bounded linear operators? How can they be determined?
I am a beginner of these topics. Please help me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.
